# Onclick of dynamic Linkbutton not firing

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, calendar, linkbutton

I've got a calendar control where I click on a day to give me a javascript popup to add a training class. On each day there might be multiple training classes. To add the classes is no problem. Then on another page I've got this exact calendar control, but with the training classes populated in each respective day with dynamic linkbuttons. On the click of the linkbutton I want to retrieve the ID of that training class which will be used to populate labels and use this ID as a reference when the manager request training for his/her employees (when inserting into sql).

I have tried adding an EventHandler, but this is not firing. I have tried using an Click attribute to this linkbutton (but cannot call a method from an attribute)... I'm not sure if I have missed something that the eventhandler is not firing, could anybody please help me on this?

This is what I have done:
DayRendering of calendar control:

```
    protected void calSchedule_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        bool result = false;

        string filterstring = "SELECT tos.[ID], sc.ServiceCenter, tos.Description " +
                              "FROM [SOS].[dbo].[TrainingOfficerSchedule] tos " +
                              "INNER JOIN [dbo].[TrainingOfficerServiceCenters] sc " +
                              "on tos.ServiceCenterRef = sc.ID " +
                              "WHERE TrainingDate = @TrainingDate";

        cn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
        SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand(filterstring, cn);
        myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrainingDate", e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString());

        cn.Open();
        SqlDataReader myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (myReader.HasRows)
        {
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                string training = myReader["ServiceCenter"].ToString() + " - " + myReader["Description"].ToString();

                LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
                lnk.ID = myReader["ID"].ToString();
                lnk.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64);
                lnk.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(192, 192, 192);

                lnk.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return getItems();");
                lnk.Click += new EventHandler(lnk_Click);
                  //lnk.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return getItems();");
                  //lnk.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "return getItems();");
                  //lnk.Attributes.Add("onclick", jsMethod(Convert.ToInt32(myReader["ID"])));
                  //lnk.Click += new EventHandler(this.lnk_Click);
                  //lnk.Atributes.Add("runat", "server");
                  //lnk.Attributes.Add("onclick", jsMethod(myReader["ID"].ToString()));
                lnk.Text = training + "<br/><br/>";
                lnk.Style.Add("cursor", "pointer");
                e.Cell.Controls.Add(lnk);
            }
        }
        cn.Close();
    }
```

Event Handler to fire when clicking on Linkbutton:

```
    public void lnk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ctrlId = ((Control)sender).ID;
        txtMManagerName.Text = ctrlId;
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "popSchedular", "showSchedular();", true);
    }
```

Is there maybe something I am doing wrong?

Comment: The issue might be that getItems is returning false hence peventing the code behing from fire. First comment out this line  lnk.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return getItems();"); and see if it wont fire.

Comment: @Bayeni, Thanks I did remove this line, but it is still not firing....

Answer (score 0):

Put down PlaceHolder where you want to display link button and then try.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph" runat="server" />


LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
            lnk.ID = myReader["ID"].ToString();
            lnk.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64);
            lnk.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(192, 192, 192);
            lnk.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return getItems();");
            lnk.Click += new EventHandler(lnk_Click);
            lnk.Text = training + "<br/><br/>";
            lnk.Style.Add("cursor", "pointer");
            ph.Controls.Add(lnk);

protected void lnk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ctrlId = ((Control)sender).ID;
    txtMManagerName.Text = ctrlId;
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "popSchedular", "showSchedular();", true);
}
```

Comment: I don't think the issue is with displaying the link button. Already in his code he's displaying the link "e.Cell.Controls.Add(lnk);".

Comment: @Dexterity, Thanks, but the Linkbutton is already displaying. The only problem is it is not firing the eventhandler... I'm trying to look at if it is possible to call a method directly from an attribute now... Thanks

Comment: Did you inspect on LinkButton in browser and check "onclick=return getItems();" event is displaying or not?? and @Bayeni is right, there is a possibility to getItems is returning false.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this before with dynamic controls. Creating multiple items with the same object reference seems to mess things up. Try creating a class that inherits from LinkButton and use that in your read loop.

```
public class myButton : LinkButton
{
    public myButton(SqlCommand sqlCmd)
    {
        var myReader = (SqlDataReader) sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
        var training = myReader["ServiceCenter"].ToString() + " - " + myReader["Description"].ToString();
        ID =myReader["ID"].ToString();
        ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64);
        BackColor = Color.FromArgb(192, 192, 192);

        Attributes.Add("onclick", "return getItems();");
        Click += new EventHandler(lnk_Click);
        Text = training + "<br/><br/>";
        Style.Add("cursor", "pointer");
    }
}
```